# mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs

I spent the whole day trying to connect my pi (**Ubuntu**) to my nas. I just want to share a specific folder.
The nas dir is called DATA.

Then there is a path to the folder I want to access. No matter what I do, I always end up getting the aforementioned error. I have attempted this in various different ways.

```
sudo mount -t nfs -O nfsvers=3,rw,credentials=/home/user/nas-credentials
192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host/ /home/username/nas
```

For example, I changed `nfsvers=3` to `nfsvers=4`, to `vers=3`, to `vers=4` to not having it.

I had my username and password in place of `credentials=/home/user/nas-credentials` like this: `username=myname,password=mypassword`.

I also had `/home/user/nas` like this: `~/nas`.

All the above I had in all kinds of configurations.

I wanted to mount the directory permanently to the pi so I edited `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=ef82352c-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=ef82352c-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that

# mount nas
192.168.178.55:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host/ /home/user/nas nfs rw,nfsvers=3,credentials=/home/user/nas-credentials,noauto 0 0
```

I also had all kinds of variations in here.

I don't know much about linux (which might be obvious).

When I type `mount` or `df -h` into the terminal a bunch of stuff show up but not `/home/user/nas`

`sudo mount -a` doesn't return anything and doesn't do anything.

This is my synology nas configuration:

[image: synology-nas-nfs-configuration]

[image: synology-nas-nfs-configuration-detail]

> **I really appreciate every bit of help but beware that I am super new to linux and might not know what you are talking about.**

**UPDATE!**

I have managed to mount the shared folder with this command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -O rw,username=username,password=password 192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host /nas
```

The Nas was giving me an access denied error. **Turns out that having the client hostname in the nfs rules above isn't such a good idea..** Changed it to it's ip-address and it mounted correctly.

The permanent mount with `/etc/fstab` still isn't working and is returning the same error as allways:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are having the issue you specified in the title of the question, if you are not, then the problem should be the /etc/fstab configuration. To mount the NFS shared folder try: `sudo mount /home/user/nas` or `sudo mount 192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host`

Comment: If you want to mount the NFS folder at boot, you should remove `noauto` option (with noauto enabled the NFS folder will not be mounted automatically at boot or when you use `mount -a`)

Comment: The `~` abbreviation for your home directory may not work in these contexts.  If it is at the beginning of a word, your shell will expand it to the real path, but in fstab or in the middle if a word, likely it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `mount` command, you're using the `-O` option. This is **not** used to provide the mount options. The flag for mount options is `-o` (lowercase `o` as opposed to uppercase `O`).

See the [manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for `mount` command:

```
-o, --options opts
   Options are specified with a -o flag followed by a comma separated string 
   of options. For example:

mount LABEL=mydisk -o noatime,nouser

...

-O, --test-opts opts

    Used in conjunction with -a, to limit the set of filesystems to which the -a 
    is applied. Like -t in this regard except that it is useless except 
    in the context of -a. For example, the command:

mount -a -O no_netdev

    mounts all filesystems except those which have the option _netdev specified
    in the options field in the /etc/fstab file.
```

The important part for `-O` is that **it is useless except in the context of -a.**

Since you didn't use the `-a` flag, this means that the options you provided after `-O` (`rw,username=username,password=password`) weren't actually used for the mount options. Effectively, your `mount` command ignored those options.

Moreover, if you had used `-o` instead of `-O`, your `mount` command would have failed because it couldn't have recognized the `username` and `password` options:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o rw,username=username,password=password 192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host /nas
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

(See the [manual pages for `nfs(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs) to find out what are the valid options for `nfs` mounts. You won't there `username`, `password` or `credentials` - which means none of those are valid mount options for `nfs` mounts)

#### Conclusion

From the fact that your `sudo mount ...` command mounted the area successfully even though it ignored your options, you could infer that you didn't actually need the `username` and `password` options to mount the filesystem in the first place. And since you didn't need them for the `mount` command, you also didn't need them in `/etc/fstab`.

So the line you need in `fstab` is just:

```
192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host /home/user/nas nfs defaults 0 0
```

And your `mount` command should have looked as as follows:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host /nas
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since the aforementioned command

```
sudo mount -t nfs -O rw,username=username,password=password 192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host /nas
```

worked the problem has to lie in `/etc/fstab`.

I will show you the conents of my file and explain what I did wrong.

```
192.168.x.x:/volume1/DATA/path/to/linux-file-host /home/user/nas nfs rw,user=username 0 0
```

First comes the host ip address followed by the path to the specific directory. As I already mentioned in my update, having the client hostname in my NFS-settings didn't work for me. I had to put in the correct ip-address. This may only apply to synology's software.

Next comes the path where you want to mount your sharepoint. I wanted it to be at `~/nas`. Having the `~/nas` or `/nas` caused an error. You have to write down the whole path! -> `/home/user/nas`.

Mind you, this only counts for the `/etc/fstab` configuration. For mounting it temporarily with `sudo mount -t nfs -O rw, ...` you have to just use `/nas`. Doing `/home/user/nas` creates a path called `/home/user/home/user/nas`.

The real issue though came with credentials.
`username` is not recognised by nsf it has to be `user`! `password` or `pass` both aren't recognised. Which kinda makes sence for nfs in hindsight. You probably don't even need an user.

Again, different for `sudo mount -t nfs -O rw, ...`. Here, `username` and `password` are recognized (or ignored, don't know).

Another step I missed was to **enable NFSv4.1 support** in my Synology settings. This is very important because it won't work otherwise.
[image: enable-NFSv4.1-support]

Something else I missed was to **"Map root to admin"** in my Synology settings. Also very importand. This was the only way it worked for me.
[image: Map-root-to-Admin]

I hope some finds this information useful and doesn't have to spend hours upon hours to set up a simple fileshare.

**Something I found really useful** but didn't know about until *chatGPT* randomly suggested it was to have a **look into `/var/log/syslog`**. There is very useful information for figuring out why something isn't working.